# Yabe Initial-Data.yml found character '\t' error

Tags: playframework, yaml

I'm working with tags in the Yabe tutorial and am running into an issue with my initial-data.yml

I already confirmed it's likeness to the samples version stopping just short of a copy and paste.

here is what I see

```
Malformed YAML 

Cannot parse the /conf/initial-data.yml file: found character '\t' that cannot start any token 


In /conf/initial-data.yml (around line 15)

11:     password:       secret
12:     fullname:       Jeff    
13: 
14: Tag(play):
15:     name:           Play
16:     
17: Tag(architecture):
18:     name:           Architecture
19:     
20: Tag(test):
21:     name:           Test
```

here is my yml

```
User(bob):
    email:          bob@gmail.com
    password:       secret
    fullname:       Bob
    isAdmin:        true

User(jeff):
    email:          jeff@gmail.com
    password:       secret
    fullname:       Jeff    

Tag(play):
    name:           Play

Tag(architecture):
    name:           Architecture

Tag(test):
    name:           Test

Tag(mvc):
    name:           MVC    

Post(firstBobPost):
    title:          About the model layer
    postedAt:       2009-06-14
    author:         bob
    content:        >
                    The model has a central position in a Play! application. It is the domain-specific 
                    representation of the information on which the application operates.

                    Martin fowler defines it as:

                    Responsible for representing concepts of the business, information about the 
                    business situation, and business rules. State that reflects the business situation 
                    is controlled and used here, even though the technical details of storing it are 
                    delegated to the infrastructure. This layer is the heart of business software.

Post(secondBobPost):
    title:          Just a test of YABE
    postedAt:       2009-03-25
    author:         bob
    content:        >
                    Well, it's just a test.

Post(jeffPost):
    title:          The MVC application
    postedAt:       2009-06-06
    author:         jeff
    tags:
                    - play
                    - architecture
                    - mvc
    content:        >
                    A Play! application follows the MVC architectural pattern as applied to the 
                    architecture of the Web.

                    This pattern splits the application into separate layers: the Presentation 
                    layer and the Model layer. The Presentation layer is further split into a 
                    View and a Controller layer.

Comment(c1):
    author:         Guest
    content:        >
                    You are right !
    postedAt:       2009-06-14
    post:           firstBobPost

Comment(c2):
    author:         Mike
    content:        >
                    I knew that ...
    postedAt:       2009-06-15
    post:           firstBobPost    

Comment(c3):
    author:         Tom
    content:        >
                    This post is useless ?
    postedAt:       2009-04-05
    post:           secondBobPost
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have tabs on line 15-23:

```
    name:\t\t\tPlay
\t
Tag(architecture):
    name:\t\t\tArchitecture
\t
Tag(test):
    name:\t\t\Test
\t
Tag(mvc):
    name:\t\t\tMVC    
\t
```

Tabs are not allowed in [yaml](http://www.yaml.org/faq.html):

> Tabs have been outlawed since they are treated differently by
>   different editors and tools. And since indentation is so critical to
>   proper interpretation of YAML, this issue is just too tricky to even
>   attempt. Indeed Guido van Rossum of Python has acknowledged that
>   allowing TABs in Python source is a headache for many people and that
>   were he to design Python again, he would forbid them.

Comment: I was able to turn on tab detection in Notepad+ and remove the offending tabs. A quick restart of the server, and everything was fine.

Thank You!

Answer (score 0):

Never use character "\t" tab in your YAML at the beginning of a line. Just use SPACES!